# Merging arrays and removing contents from old array in a single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm calling a method that I want to return a merged array.  It returns in an if statement, so it will only return the last line.  I want it to both merge (through `.concat`) `@old_array` to `@new_array` and also delete the contents of `@old_array` in the same line.  How would I go about doing this?

```
    if test == @good_test
      @new_array.concat(@old_array) #I want it to return this
      @old_array = [].   #while also deleting this
  end
```

Comment: Add a 3rd line containing the return value, i.e. `@new_array`

Comment: `@new_array, @old_array = [@new_array + @old_array]`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to "remove contents from old array", but that's not what your code does. `@old_array = []` doesn't remove the contents of the object referenced by `@old_array`, it assigns a new array.

Comment: @new_array.concat(@old_array); @old_array = [] <- Works like magic.

Comment: yet another way - `@new_array.concat(@old_array).tap { @old_array.clear }`

Comment: Your code doesn't show an attempt to solve the problem. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array's [`slice!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) to delete elements given by an index and length, or a range, and return the elements deleted from the array:

```
def do_it(new_array, old_array)
  if true
    new_array.concat(old_array.slice!(0..-1))
  end
end

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
do_it(a, b) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
b # => []
```

If you don't have end-less range's in your ruby version, you can just use `-1` as the end:

```
old_array.slice!(0..-1)
```

Eye-balling the source, this looks like it'll create a new array and copy all the elements over to it and then clears the existing array and then returns the new array. Efficient? Not really, does what you ask? Yep.